# UML of DataBase

Tags: sql, relational-database, uml, composite-primary-key

I am going to create web app where the users can rate books, add a chapter of book to their cart, buy then download. [Here is my uml of db](https://ibb.co/zhDTh2b). `book` and `chapter` have “one to many” relationship, but I created composite primary key from foreign key of book id `b_id` and chapter id  `c_id` to identify chapters number in the books. `chapter` and `user` have “many to many” relationship, because one `chapter` can be bought by many users and one `user` can buy many books. And I created “many to many” relationship between book and user tables for 5 star rating system. Is it bad that the `book` separately also has a relationship with `user` table and I have to choose between `chapter` and rating (`user_m2m_book`) tables.

I'm not sure if my schema is in 3rd normal form. Could such a composite primary key as in the `user_m2m_chapter` table lead to some serious problems? Any other mistakes in my schema?

I know that many decisions have to made based on the subject area. But I am doing it for myself and asking for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the expert, but I think rather than linking chapter to the user establish a relation between user and book with "Many-to-Many" relationship. And, also create a relationship between book and chapter same "Many-to-Many". This way User and Book will have relationship and with the help of JOIN you can get the chapter as well via BookId in Chapter's table.
*Note: Better if you create one table where you can store user and book information where same user will have many books id or vice-versa.*

Comment: Thanks for answer! If I create "Many-to-Many" relationship between book and chapter then how I will identify chapters order in the book. Chapters instead of names have their IDs and I want to display them in web like this:
**BookName:**
Chapter-1       [add to cart] [buy],
Chapter-2       [add to cart] [buy].
Or I didn't get something.

Comment: @HeroHamada, How about one-to-many relationship between book to chapter. One book will have multiple chapter. So either you can create bookChapter table or store in chapter table with duplicate foreign keys (bookId)

Comment: Do I need to add the foreign key of the book to the primary key of chapters?

Comment: @HeroHamada, Yes you do but as a column bookId not as PK. PK will be ChapterId